# Why are encrypted stored procedures taking a long time to execute in SQL Server 2022?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, stored-procedures, sql-server-2022

Why are encrypted stored procedures taking a long time to execute in SQL Server 2022?

Is there any specific settings or configuration at server level?

Our large procedures are working fine in SQL Server 2019 with encryption. But in SQL Server 2022 It's taking a very long time to execute.

Need some setting or configuration idea to make execution fast with encryption.

In the procedure, we just have simple insert statements. and when we had removed With encryption from procedure. It works faster as it was working in SQL 2019.

Comment: I doubt there is a magic go-faster button. You probably need to inspect the execution plan and debug why it's slow. Different versions of SQL Server generate different query plans, usually they improve, but not always.

Comment: Why do you use encrypted procs at all, they don't offer a lot of protection because you can still see the queries they are executing

Comment: So you have two *identical* procedures with *identical* query plans, one encrypted and one not, and the encrypted procedure is slower?

Comment: yes @Charlieface, for SQL server 2022

Comment: @siggemannen
We are using encryption to hide our code from directly access at client location.

Comment: Extraordinary claims need extraordinary evidence. You would need to show that.

Comment: The encryption doesn't provide any real protection anyway. Why bother? Anybody with google and about 10 minutes can crack it. If you truly want to hide your logic use CLR but even that can be cracked pretty easily.